# alignment problems in php while loop

Tags: php, html, css, pdo, alignment

Here i don't have any coding related problem. I'm trying to fetch the details from multiple database tables. fetch results working fine. But alignment is my problem here.

[image]

You can see a image.. In that image voucher status column is working fine. But, another two column ( room status & meal status values ) is always on the last row. How to align those (room and meal status) values properly (like voucher status column)? i hope you can understand my problem...

```
      <?php
        echo "<table width=1090 border=1 style=\"border: #ddd;\" align=center cellspacing=4 cellpadding=10>";
        echo "<tr class=thvoucher>";
        echo "<th width=30>Voucher Number</th>";
        echo "<th width=80>Reference Number</th>";
        echo "<th width=200>Guest Name</th>";
        echo "<th width=150>Voucher Status</th>";
        echo "<th width=150>Room Status</th>";
        echo "<th width=150>Meal Status</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) 
        {
            if ($i == $total_results) 
            {
                break;
            }
            while($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
               $voucherid = $row['VoucherID'];
           $ref = $row['VoucherReference'];
           $gname = $row['GuestName'];
           $vstatus = $row['ActiveStatus'];
           echo "<tr class=voucherstyle" . $cls . ">";
           echo "<td>$voucherid</td>";    **// FIRST TD**
           echo "<td>$ref</td>";    **// SECOND TD**
           echo "<td>$gname</td>";     **// THIRD TD**

                      if( $vstatus != 'empty' )       **// FOURTH TD**
        {
            if( $vstatus == 'Y' )
            {
                echo "<td class=green >Active</td>";
            }
            else if( $vstatus == 'N' )
            {
                echo "<td class=red >Inactive</td>";
            }
        }
        else
            {
                echo "<td><form method=post onsubmit=\"return mstatusvalidate(this)\"; action='voucherstatus_update.php?id_meal= $voucherid '><select name=mealstatus><option value=empty></option><option value=active>Active</option><option value=inactive>Inactive</option></select><input type=submit class=update_status title=\"Update $gname voucher status\" value=Update></form></td>";
            }
            }

            while($r_row = $r_stmt->fetch())
            {
                $rstatus = $r_row['ActiveStatus'];

                        // same like above if else statement      **// FIFTH TD**
            }       

            while($m_row = $m_stmt->fetch())
            {
                $mstatus = $m_row['ActiveStatus']; 

                        // same like above if else statement  **// SIXTH TD**       
            }
echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            ?>
```

Comment: you are not closing the <tr> tag inside your loop.. furthermore you declared 6 table titles.. but you only output 3 of them.

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't seem to emit any HTML for the cells you are having trouble aligning. I don't see how we can help from this.

Comment: @Yami : i've used 6 td. i did't posted if else statement code here. so, only you didn't see remaining td. i've used another 3 td is in if else statement. i've updated my codes. see again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using this while condition `while(($row = $stmt->fetch()) && ($r_row = $r_stmt->fetch()) && ($m_row = $m_stmt->fetch()))`. Before i've used **three separate while loops**. Now, i've some other ideas. i tried it, now its working fine and alignment also perfect. Before i didn't post my if else statement code. So, everyone thought i've used just 3 td's. Sorry for confused everyone... I've posted my correct coding below..

```
     <?php
        echo "<table width=1090 border=1 style=\"border: #ddd;\" align=center cellspacing=4 cellpadding=10>";
        echo "<tr class=thvoucher>";
        echo "<th width=30>Voucher Number</th>";
        echo "<th width=80>Reference Number</th>";
        echo "<th width=200>Guest Name</th>";
        echo "<th width=150>Voucher Status</th>";
        echo "<th width=150>Room Status</th>";
        echo "<th width=150>Meal Status</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) 
        {
            if ($i == $total_results) 
            {
                break;
            }
            while(($row = $stmt->fetch()) && ($r_row = $r_stmt->fetch()) && ($m_row = $m_stmt->fetch()))
            {
                $voucherid = $row['VoucherID'];
                $ref = $row['VoucherReference'];
                $gname = $row['GuestName'];
                $vstatus = $row['ActiveStatus'];
                echo "<tr class=voucherstyle" . $cls . ">";
                echo "<td>$voucherid</td>";       **1st TD**
                echo "<td>$ref</td>";      **2nd TD**
                echo "<td>$gname</td>";      **3rd TD**
                if( $vstatus != 'empty' )      **4th TD**
                {
                    if( $vstatus == 'Y' )
                    {
                        echo "<td class=green >Active</td>";
                    }
                    else if( $vstatus == 'N' )
                    {
                        echo "<td class=red >Inactive</td>";
                    }
                }
                else
                    {
                        echo "<td><form method=post onsubmit=\"return mstatusvalidate(this)\"; action='voucherstatus_update.php?id= $voucherid '><select name=mealstatus><option value=empty></option><option value=active>Active</option><option value=inactive>Inactive</option></select><input type=submit class=update_status title=\"Update $gname voucher status\" value=Update></form></td>";
                    }

                $rstatus = $r_row['ActiveStatus'];
                // if else statement      **5th TD**

                $mstatus = $m_row['ActiveStatus'];
                // if else statement      **6th TD**
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 6 th elements in your first row, but I only see 3 td elements and no tr closing tags on subsequent rows. This is likely your issue.

I would suspect that a cursory inspection of your source output would have made this pretty clear.

Comment: i've used 6 td. i did't posted if else statement code here. so, only you didn't see the remaining 3 td. i've used another 3 td is in if else statement. i've updated my codes. see again

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
echo "<table width=1090 border=1 style=\"border: #ddd;\" align=center cellspacing=4 cellpadding=10>";
echo "<tr class=thvoucher>";
echo "<th width=30>Voucher Number</th>";
echo "<th width=80>Reference Number</th>";
echo "<th width=200>Guest Name</th>";
echo "<th width=150>Voucher Status</th>";
echo "<th width=150>Room Status</th>";
echo "<th width=150>Meal Status</th>";
echo "</tr>";
for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) 
{
    if ($i == $total_results) 
    {
        break;
    }
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        $voucherid = $row['VoucherID'];
        $ref = $row['VoucherReference'];
        $gname = $row['GuestName'];
        $vstatus = $row['ActiveStatus'];
        echo "<tr class=voucherstyle" . $cls . ">";
        echo "<td>$voucherid</td>";    **// FIRST TD**
        echo "<td>$ref</td>";    **// SECOND TD**
        echo "<td>$gname</td>";     **// THIRD TD**

        if( $vstatus != 'empty' )       **// FOURTH TD**
        {
            if( $vstatus == 'Y' )
            {
                echo "<td class=green >Active</td>";
            }
            else if( $vstatus == 'N' )
            {
                echo "<td class=red >Inactive</td>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td><form method=post onsubmit=\"return mstatusvalidate(this)\"; action='voucherstatus_update.php?id_meal= $voucherid '><select name=mealstatus><option value=empty></option><option value=active>Active</option><option value=inactive>Inactive</option></select><input type=submit class=update_status title=\"Update $gname voucher status\" value=Update></form></td>";
        }

        while($r_row = $r_stmt->fetch())
        {
            $rstatus = $r_row['ActiveStatus'];

            // same like above if else statement      **// FIFTH TD**
        }       

        while($m_row = $m_stmt->fetch())
        {
            $mstatus = $m_row['ActiveStatus']; 

                    // same like above if else statement  **// SIXTH TD**       
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: edited the answer. try it.
Fifth and Sixth <td> while loop need to be inside the first while loop. check the above answer

Comment: i already tried it. it would not work. if i do i like this room and meal status values (all) are shown in the first row...